# Sending Array from content script to background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I send an array from content script to background script it becomes undefined in background script.
Content Script:

```
var sendLink = [];
var canList = document.querySelectorAll(".userName.name");
for(i=0;i<canList.length;i++)
{
    sendLink[i] = canList[i].href; 
    console.log(sendLink[i]);   //shows correct links
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(sendLink, function(response) {
    console.log(`message from background: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);  // shows undefined
    });
```

Background Script:

```
var recLink = [];
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    recLink = request.sendLink;
    sendResponse({ result: recLink[0] });   //gives error cannot read property 0 of undefined.
    chrome.tabs.create({url: recLink[0]});
    window.open(recLink[0]);
    return true; 
});
```

Please tell me whats wrong and how do I send the array successfully.

Comment: Should be `recLink = request` because you're sending an array, not an object so it doesn't have `sendLink` property. Also you really really need to start using devtools debugger where you can set breakpoints and see what's being sent and what's being received. The background page has its [own devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029).

Comment: thanks bro wOxxOm its working now, I didn't knew about devtools debugger, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
recLink = request;
```

instead of

```
recLink = request.sendLink;
```

in background script. Thanks to @wOxxOm for solving it.